# SSO with Azure AD and GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Hey I am wondering if anyone knows how to set up sso with gcp with Azure ad being the third party idp? The problem I'm facing is we are applying to the production environment and we need to add sso by a single user basis. How would i go about configuring just one user on gcp to utilize AAD for sign on? I seen something in reference to adding the "network mask" of the user but im having trouble locating it?

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted yesterday by Bhargav Rao♦.
I believe the following documentation references would help you:

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) with Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector.

1.first you need to add Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector from the gallery

2.you need to enable sso for that application

3.you need to create a test user and add user to application

4.configure google cloud sso(for this you need to login to Google cloud Gsuite admin console).

5.now you need to create google(G suite) cloud  connector test user.
All the configuration steps are available in this Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial#configure-google-cloud-g-suite-connector-sso.

**Note**: We Cannot enable single sign-on for only a subset of Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector users. Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector doesn't support having multiple identity providers, the identity provider for your Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector environment can either be Azure AD or Google -- but not both at the same time.

Comment: This is the message im recieving after following all the steps

Comment: AADSTS650056: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the following: the client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, the admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Or, check the certificate in the request to ensure it's valid. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant. Client app ID: 01303a13-8322-4e06-bee5-80d612907131.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Google SSO profile assigments by using group, user or Organization and have it bypass 3rd party IDP authentication and instead authenticate against Google. See starting at step 5. Haven't tested it but working on it now.
https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F60224%3Fhl%3Den&product_context=60224&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.